# Specifying type hints of overridden methods in generic collection

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, collections, types

I have defined an abstract base class `BaseRepository` that acts as a collection of items with specified supertype `Foo`. 
The convenience classmethods in `BaseRepository` are annotated/type hinted to work with objects of type `Foo`. Here is a minimal example:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
NoReturn = None

class Foo(object):
    pass  # simple data holding object


class BaseRepository(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    # May be filled with subtypes of `Foo` later
    _items = None  # type: List[Foo]

    @classmethod
    def get_item(cls) -> Foo:
        return cls._items[0]

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def _load_items(cls) -> NoReturn:
        pass
```

Now there are multiple static implementations (e.g. `SubRepository`) which are each supposed to work with their own type of items (like `Bar`), being subclasses of the original generic type `Foo`.

```
class Bar(Foo):
    pass  # Must implement Foo in order for BaseRepository's methods to work

def load_some_bars():
    return [Bar(),Bar()]

class SubRepository(BaseRepository):
    # Inherits `get_item` from BaseRepository

    @classmethod
    def _load_items(cls) -> NoReturn:
        cls._items = load_some_bars()
```

The repositories are static, meaning that they are not instantiated but rather function as namespaces for proper access to items that I load from YAML configuration files. The main perk is that I can create one of these `SubRepositories` and simply override the deserialization method `_load_items`, and the resulting repository will have all convenience methods from the base class. As I need to ensure that all of these `SubRepositories` work with items `Foo` that have a specific interface in order for the `BaseRepository` methods function properly, the `SubRepositories` must work with items that inherit from `Foo`.

Strongly-typed languages like Java or C# have the concept of **Generic Collections**, where the elements in the subclassed collections all assume a specific type. 
Is the same possible with type hinting in Python?
In particular, I would like the inherited `get_item` method in `SubRepository` to be hinted as `Bar` with minimal effort (not override it just for the sake of type hints). Optimally, the correct return value should be linted by PyCharm.

Currently, even though `SubRepository` holds `Bar` items, my autocompletion in PyCharm only shows me members of `Foo`.

I read about `typing.Generic` and `TypeVar`, but I'm unsure how to use them in this case.

Comment: Can you use Python v3.5+?  You might be able to work something out with the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module.  I'll let my ignorance show .... Are you trying to force a paradigm from other languages into Python's ?  Do you instantiate your classes or are you using the objects themselves as containers?

Comment: Yes, the typing solution is what I'm looking for. I read about `Generic[...]` and `TypeVar`, but am not sure how they help in this context. The objects themselves are static classes with static items, yes, as they represent config values I load from yaml files.

Comment: To be clear,it is too much effort to override the method just for the type hint when the method suite will just be a call to the `super`'s method?. --> `def get_item(cls) -> Bar:  return super().get_item()`

Comment: Sure, that's my current workaround. I might also look into .pyi files which allow specifying type hints in a separate file, preventing clutter. However, I'm looking for the most idiomatic solution and I'd be amazed if there wasn't a way to get this to work now that we finally have pseudo-strong types in python . Thanks for the edits btw, appreciated.

Comment: `...So if you really, really want type hints, there's really no alternative to specifying them everywhere you want them.` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389249/2823755

Comment: See the q&a at the bottom of the comments to this SO answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064289/2823755

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're programming to an interface, so only `Foo` members are exposed.

```
from typing import get_type_hints
print(get_type_hints(SubRepository.get_item))
```

Output:

```
{'return': <class '__main__.Foo'>}
```

A generic collection will expose the generic type's members.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_type_hints
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
NoReturn = None

# type variable with an upper bound
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Foo)

class BaseRepository(Generic[T], metaclass=ABCMeta):
    _items = None  # type: List[T]

    @classmethod
    def get_item(cls) -> T:
        return cls._items[0]

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def _load_items(cls) -> NoReturn:
        pass

class SubRepository(BaseRepository[Bar]):
    # Inherits `get_item` from BaseRepository

    @classmethod
    def _load_items(cls) -> NoReturn:
        cls._items = load_some_bars()
```

Return type

```
print(get_type_hints(SubRepository.get_item))
```

Passes the buck

```
{'return': ~T}
```

Autocompletion will now show members of `Bar`.

Comment: I don't have an IDE that makes use of the hints.  I didn't know if the correct type would show up for the sub-class - mine just shows `~T`.